# Authentication using Apache2.2 without default browser pop up

Tags: apache, authentication, basic-authentication, apache2.2

I have a static website and I wish to make use Apache 2.2 authentication. I want the user to be redirected to my custom login page(Instead of the default windows pop up that appears) if they try to directly access my site pages via URL. I succeeded with the approach when I used mod_auth_form module of Apache2.4. Is there any way I can achieve the same using Apache2.2 only ?

Note: I'm using HTML, JavaScript only.

Thanks